Help With Model consisting of individual Components
Wow. the mods are really toxic here. 2nd time my question is closed.
I have very little experience with Blender and just need this model to do a movie for fun. The problem is the gap that exists at the neck.  I tried editing the head and torso to eliminate the  gap but it still left gaps when animated. The model is made up of separate components for the head, hair, feet, torso, legs, etc.
If anyone can fix it, I would really appreciate it. If not, I understand. Thanks!
As seen in the picture, the body is there for reference to ensure the head has no gaps with the body. Once the gap is gone I will delete the body and save the head alone. I just imported the body and the head as the others aren't required to fix the gap between head and body. The model is from the GTA V game.
Blender File :



Please edit your original question so that it is clear and answerable instead of asking the same question again. Thank you for your understanding!

Is that your job as a mod, to close topics because you don't understand them?

Your original Q is still open here. The reason you haven't received answers might be because it doesn't fully align with the site's format or lacks sufficient detail. See How to Ask a good Question. Please note that this community is run by volunteers who contribute their time and expertise as they are able. Posting the same question multiple times will not increase your chances of getting an answer; it will only clutter the site.

@user22745407 Instead of ranting about it, you could have spent the past 15 days since your first post going through beginner tutorials, which would have helped you learn how to model and fix the issue yourself.
